# Alternatives to Nodequeue?

Tags: nodes

Are there any other modules that can implement the same functionality as [Nodequeues](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) i.e, making a customized list of selected nodes? I think I might be having some problems which might be related to it's permissions (I'm not sure of it as I'm still novice at Drupal). Maybe it's because it is still in beta phase for D7, I don't know...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All about that matter [here](http://drupal.org/node/398508).

Current options are:

- [Outline Designer](http://drupal.org/project/outline_designer)
- [Weight](http://drupal.org/project/weight)
- [Nodeorder](http://drupal.org/project/nodeorder)
- [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue)
- [DraggableViews](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews)
- [Flag Weights](http://drupal.org/project/flag_weights)
- [Sortable Grid Views Plugin](http://drupal.org/project/sgrid)
- [JQGRID](http://drupal.org/project/jqgrid)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [flag module](http://drupal.org/project/flag) to do something similar, and if you combine it with [Draggable views](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) and [Flag weights](http://drupal.org/project/flag_weights) you can re-order them. Just define a flag for each node queue you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced [NodeQueue](https://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) usage with [Entity Collection](https://drupal.org/project/entity_collection). It's both entity and storage backend agnostic, as well as plays well with exportability.

Comment: any idea on when there will be a release? THX!

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to add [Entityqueue](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityqueue) to the list as well.

> A rewrite of Nodequeue for Drupal 7 based on entities.
>
> The Entityqueue module allows users to create queues of any entity
>   type. Each queue is implemented as an Entityreference field, that can
>   hold a single entity type.
>
> For instance you can create a queue of:
>
> - Nodes
> - Users
> - Taxonomy Terms
>
> Entityqueue provides Views integration, by adding an Entityqueue
>   relationship to your view, and adding a sort for Entityqueue position.